# Rebind Partial View Elements after Ajax call

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

```
$('#approveRequest').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#approveRequest').data('url'),
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#accountGroupAdmin').html(result);
            }
    });
    });
```

How do I rebind the elements are the partial view is refreshed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) with [jquery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The static parent should remain during refresh.

```
$('staticParentIdCouldBeBody').on('click', '#approveRequest', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#approveRequest').data('url'),
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
                $('#accountGroupAdmin').html(result);
            }
    });
});
```

[Delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers